# awk include current date as the last column in a file and print out the contents as column delimited

Tags: printing

I am using the following to include current date as last column in a file and print the contents of the file as tab delimited

awk -v OFS='\t' -v cdate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') '/^[[:digit:]]+/ {$4=cdate; print}' file3

File3 contents

cat file3
ITEM    APP     PRI_COST
1       E_JI    456
2       E_MI    789
3       Suy_TY  765
4       Ergjyujhgr123

But I get the O/P as below

1       E_JI    456     2020-11-27
2       E_MI    789     2020-11-27
3       Suy_TY  765     2020-11-27
4       Ergjyujhgr123           2020-11-27

Desired O/P should be

1       E_JI    456     2020-11-27
2       E_MI    789     2020-11-27
3       Suy_TY  765     2020-11-27
4       Ergjyujhgr123   2020-11-27

Could someone assist me please?

Regards,

Comment: Sorry the title should have said tab limited

Answer (score 0):

its OK, I figured this out by using printf. Thanks all